# Divide band by another band using img.split()

Tags: python, merge, split, python-imaging-library

I have a 24-bit jpeg picture that I am trying to manipulate. I want to divide the red band by the green band (then normalize from 0 to 255). Then merge the bands with the g=0 and b=0. I have tried using the img.split() and img.merge() method but it doesnt work. At the end I also want to change it to an 8 but. I believe the img.convert('L') will do it. Can someone please help me?

```
import Image

img = Image.open("M10.jpg")
img.convert("RGB") 

r,g,b=img.split()
p=r/g
g=g.point(lambda i:i*0)
b=b.point(lambda i:i*0)
out=Image.merge('RGB',(p,g,b))
out.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Image

#load image, get bands and pixel arrays
img = Image.open('sample.jpg')
r,g,b = img.split()
r_array = r.load()
g_array = g.load()
b_array = b.load()
x,y = r.size

#divide red band by green band (+1 to prevent divide by 0)
for i in xrange(x):
  for j in xrange(y):
    r_array[i, j] /= (g_array[i, j] + 1)

#normalize red band, set green and blue to 0
scalar = 255.0 / r.getextrema()[1]
for i in xrange(x):
  for j in xrange(y):
    r_array[i, j] *= scalar
    g_array[i, j] = 0 
    b_array[i, j] = 0 

#merge the bands
img = Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b)) 
img = img.convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=8)
img.show()
```

I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to accomplish, hope it helps.